# How to store complex object in redis hash in c#?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have to store complex object into hash of redis cash.I am using stackexchange.redis to do this.My Class is like below.

```
 public class Company
   {
      public string CompanyName { get; set; }
      public List<User> UserList { get; set; }
   }
   public class User
   {

    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Blog { get; set; }
   }
```

My code snippet to store data in redis is:

```
db.HashSet("Red:10000",comapny.ToHashEntries());
```

//Serialize in Redis format:

```
public static HashEntry[] ToHashEntries(this object obj)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    return properties
        .Where(x => x.GetValue(obj) != null) // <-- PREVENT NullReferenceException
        .Select(property => new HashEntry(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj)
        .ToString())).ToArray();
}
```

I could store the data in redis but not as i want.I am geting result as shown in below image.
[image: result after saving data in redis desktop manager]
I want `UserList` value in json format.So,how can i do this.

Comment: You could try [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis), a wrapper around SE.Redis with enhancements like a configurable serialization mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest path is checking if each property value is a collection (see the comments in my modified version of your method):

```
public static HashEntry[] ToHashEntries(this object obj)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    return properties
        .Where(x => x.GetValue(obj) != null) // <-- PREVENT NullReferenceException
        .Select
        (
              property => 
              {
                   object propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj);
                   string hashValue;

                   // This will detect if given property value is 
                   // enumerable, which is a good reason to serialize it
                   // as JSON!
                   if(propertyValue is IEnumerable<object>)
                   {
                         // So you use JSON.NET to serialize the property
                         // value as JSON
                         hashValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertyValue);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        hashValue = propertyValue.ToString();
                   }

                   return new HashEntry(property.Name, hashValue);
              }
        )
        .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is something wrong with serializing. The best way of converting between JSON and .NET object is using the [JsonSerializer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fooObject);
```

You can see more details from [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Also there is another good way,you can try to use `IRedisTypedClient` which is a part of ServiceStack.Redis.

> [IRedisTypedClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisTypedClient) - A high-level 'strongly-typed' API available
>   on Service Stack's C# Redis Client to make all Redis Value operations
>   to apply against any c# type. Where all complex types are
>   transparently serialized to JSON using ServiceStack JsonSerializer -
>   The fastest JSON Serializer for .NET.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But isn't this question about SE.Redis?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Sorry about that,I have updated my answer,and it seems that there is something wrong with serializing,and it's a good way to use Json.NET.